# How to add js var inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Somehow I can't make the var "turn" change.

--------------'#a3' is a div-----------------

For all of the code go [here](http://jsfiddle.net/greyscalesstudios/7VDFG/32/).

Here is some of the js/jquery:

```
var turn = 1;

if (turn === 1) {

//----------------------------red
if (da3 === false) {
    $('#a3').click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        turn = 0;
    });
}

if (turn === 0) {

//----------------------------blue
if (da3 === false) {
    $('#a3').click(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
       turn = 1;
    });
}
```

Here is some css I used:

```
div {
display: inline-block;
background-color:grey;
width : 150px;
height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? That the pages background-color toggles, if you click on the `a3` element?

Comment: When you click are you relaunching the whole javascript you put? Also, when you assign 2 click events to an element it does both. You probably need to unbind it first and then re run it.

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: Are you going for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HVQgg/?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you only add one event handler that only does one thing. It is not magically going to add the other one.

Do the if/else logic inside of the click events.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is structured like this:

```
var turn = 1;  // red turn first
if (turn === 1) {
    // assign click handlers for red moves
}
if (turn === 0) {
    // assign click handlers for blue moves
}
```

The problem with this is that the only click handlers that will ever be used here are the ones defined in the `if (turn === 1)` block.  The code will not be re-evaluated when you modify `turn` so the click handlers for blue will never be used.

Instead it should look something like this:

```
var turn = 1;  // red turn first
// example click handler:
$('#a3').click(function () {
    // check whose turn it is *inside* of the click handler
    if (turn === 0) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        turn = 1;
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        turn = 0;
    }
});
// other click handlers like the above (or better yet, reuse the same function)
```

Comment: The turn variable would be shared between the different tile handlers, which would mean clicking one tile, then another would skip the second tile straight to its second state. I`m assuming `"background-color", "blue"` for both handlers is a typo.

Comment: Its a tic-tac-toe game, the intent is to only have each tile clicked once and each click would change whose turn it is (and the background color used).

Comment: I see. So I suppose tiles that have been clicked before are supposed to remain unaffected by clicks?

Comment: Yeah that would really be the correct way to implement this, the background color and turn flag should only be changed if it hasn't already been changed to red or blue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle the background-color by clicking the a3-element, you need to do the if/else checking *inside* of the event-handler:

```
bg_state = 0;

$('#a3').click(function () {
    if (bg_state===0) {
       $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        bg_state=1;
    } else {
       $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        bg_state=0;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ADUV9/

The setting of the event-handler is only executed one time, when the page loads!